# How can I read a number from a file and store it as a float in a list? / Python

Tags: python, list, floating-point

(this is my first ever question, so I apologise if it's not very clear)

I have a text file which looks something like this:

```
106.33333333333333
200.79263333333
68.214276154075
```

and I would like to put each number into a list (as a float) which can then be used to work out the average, maximum and sum. ( mean() , max() , sum() )

---

I've tried a number of variations based on similar question responses of: (simplified code)

```
    whod = []

    filename = (whouser+' '+d)

    for line in filename:
        numbers = line.rstrip('\n')
        whod = whod + [float(numbers)]

    print(whod)
```

then to check,

```
print(list)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 's'
```

---

To be honest I didn't expect it work but if you have any suggestions that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use the names of Python builtins as variables. Also, just use `list.append(float(numbers))` instead of `list = list + float(numbers)`.

Comment: @MattDMo is referring to your use of "file" and "list" as variables. file() docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file  list() docs:                                        https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list

Comment: yup sorry, I changed my code that so it'd make more sense to a viewer. rookie mistake apparently haha. updating the q now.

Comment: Assuming the code shown really is the exact code you ran (*is it?*), the only way you can possibly have gotten the specific error message you got, is if there is a line consisting of just an 's' (and nothing else) in the file you are reading.  You would get a similar error message for any line that `float()` can't parse.

Comment: A good way to learn how to solve this kind of problem is to try printing out variables at each step of the process, and see where your understanding of what's supposed to happen fails to match what's actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension and a `with` statement to open the file:

```
with open('text.txt') as text:
    data = [float(i) for i in text]
```

Then you can simply call your built-in methods on the `data` list:

```
max_value = max(data)
sum_value = sum(data)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you; however, this is a good answer as far as "how do I code this thing in idiomatic Python", but it *doesn't address the OP's problem at all*.  If I'm right about their real problem, they would get the exact same `ValueError` with this as with the code they have.

Comment: Hmm, actually I take that back, the OP has substantially changed their question since you posted this answer.  This is a good answer to the *original* question.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you suggesting that file contains non-numeric values?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I think is the OP's *current* problem.

Comment: @zwol Should I include some regex to circumvent that?

Comment: Without knowing what *should* be done with lines that aren't valid floating-point numbers, I don't think it's useful to suggest ways to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

First a quick note: As MattDMo pointed out, you want to avoid using builtins as variable names. In your example, thats `list` and `file`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file

---

```py
with open('filename.txt','r') as numbers_file:
    numbers = [float(n) for n in numbers_file]

print 'numbers: %s' % numbers
numbers_max = max(numbers)
print 'max: %s' % numbers_max
numbers_sum = sum(numbers)
print 'sum: %s' % numbers_sum
numbers_mean = numbers_sum / float(len(numbers))
print 'mean: %s' % numbers_mean
```

If you are still getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 's'
```

You need to make sure that every item in the file can be cast as a float exactly as is. If you want to read the file in a more resilient way:

```
numbers = []
with open('filename.txt','r') as numbers_file:
    for line in numbers_file:
        try:
            num = float(line.strip())
            numbers.append(num)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

This will ensure that you only read the lines from the file that are numbers.

---

The code inside the brackets, `[float(n) for n in numbers_file]` will iterate over the lines in the `numbers_file` (filename.txt) and cast each item as `float` while building the list. The resulting list is then passed to `extend` which updates the original `numbers` list. Iterating over a list like this in one line of code is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Here's the python docs on `list` methods:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: That's nearly the same answer I have. And it's pointless to extend an empty list. Just assign the list to the comprehension as I have done.

Comment: Why make numbers in the first place? You could have just done `numbers = <list comp>` inside.

Comment: The OP made it seem like there would be a persistent list in the script that would be updated from multiple files, so I didn't make any other assumptions.

Comment: `n.strip().isdigit()` is True for `12345` but not `123.45`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = my_list + [float(numbers)]
```

Comment: [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is the more Pythonic way to do it.